# JPA ManyToOne with composite key

Tags: jpa, orm

I have this model mapping for a **Brand** entity:

```
@Entity
public class Brand implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private BrandPk id;

//...
}
```

The composite key is:

```
@Embeddable
public class BrandPk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id1;

    private int id2;
//...
}
```

Now I want to join a **Product** entity (one brand, many products):

I will have:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

@ManyToOne
// ???
private Brand brand;

//...
}
```

What will I need to correctly join my tables-entities?

*table_brands* has a PK composing two fields: id1 and id2
*table_products* has a PK with an id, and a field **id_brand** refering just to id1.

**id2 is not used anymore and not important at all!**

This mapping is for a legacy DB that unfortunately I cannot change, so I need to join "ignoring" id2. 
How can I?

Comment: `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="id_brand")`

Comment: ... results in Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering model.Brand from model.Product has the wrong number of column. should be 2"}}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add another column say id_brand2 referring to id2, you can try this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name="id_brand", referencedColumnName="id1"),
     @JoinColumn(name="id_brand2", referencedColumnName="id2")
})
private Brand brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JDK 8 the `@JoinColumns` wrapper is no longer necessary, could be just like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_brand", referencedColumnName="id1"),
@JoinColumn(name="id_brand2", referencedColumnName="id2")
private Brand brand;
```